# D3 Force Layout: How to dynamically orient teardrop-shaped nodes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nodes, shapes, force-layout

I want to have teardrop-shaped nodes with dynamic orientation, such that the directionality of the node alone reveals its source and target node. 
This is my code so far (the code for the teardrop was taken from this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/849853) and the graph it produces:

http://jsbin.com/kigiwinida/edit?html,output

But what I ultimately want is something like this picture:

[image: picture]

I think the key to making the teardrops' orientation dynamic is giving the right argument to the rotate() function; make the teardrops rotate accordingly so as to align with the edges they're targets of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this...

```js
var w = window.innerWidth*2,
    h = window.innerHeight*3,
    r = 10,
    charge = 300,
    def_color = "#bdbdbd"; //default node color
    



    var dataset =   {"nodes": 
    [
    {"x": 469, "y": 410},
    {"x": 493, "y": 364},
    {"x": 442, "y": 365},
    {"x": 467, "y": 314},
    {"x": 477, "y": 248},
    {"x": 425, "y": 207},
    {"x": 402, "y": 155},
    {"x": 369, "y": 196},
    {"x": 350, "y": 148},
    {"x": 539, "y": 222},
    {"x": 594, "y": 235},
    {"x": 582, "y": 185},
    {"x": 633, "y": 200}
     ],
  "edges": [
    {"source":  0, "target":  1},
    {"source":  1, "target":  2},
    {"source":  2, "target":  0},
    {"source":  1, "target":  3},
    {"source":  3, "target":  2},
    {"source":  3, "target":  4},
    {"source":  4, "target":  5},
    {"source":  5, "target":  6},
    {"source":  5, "target":  7},
    {"source":  6, "target":  7},
    {"source":  6, "target":  8},
    {"source":  7, "target":  8},
    {"source":  9, "target":  4},
    {"source":  9, "target": 11},
    {"source":  9, "target": 10},
    {"source": 10, "target": 11},
    {"source": 11, "target": 12},
    {"source": 12, "target": 10}
  ]
};


    //Initialize a default force layout, using the nodes and edges in dataset
    var force = d3.layout.force()
         .nodes(dataset.nodes)
         .links(dataset.edges)
         .size([w, h])
         .linkDistance([70]);

    //Create SVG container element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .attr("class", "svg-container")

    //Build the arrow
    svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
      .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
      .enter().append("marker")
      .attr("id", function (d) { return d; })
      .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
      .attr("refX", 50)
      //.attr("refY", 0)
      .attr("markerWidth", 6)
      .attr("markerHeight", 6)
      .attr("orient", "auto")
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
      .style("stroke", "#ccc");


    //Create edges as lines
    var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
      .data(dataset.edges)
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("marker-end", "url(#suit)") //Add the arrow
      .style("stroke", "#ccc")
      .style("stroke-width", 1);



            // Create the groups under svg
    var gnodes = svg.selectAll('g.gnode')
      .data(dataset.nodes)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .classed('gnode', true);

    // Add one circle in each group
    var node = gnodes.append("path")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("d", raindrop(r))
        .style("fill", def_color)
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .call(force.drag);

    function raindrop(size) {
      var r = size;
      return "M" + r + ",0"
        + "A" + r + "," + r + " 0 1,1 " + -r + ",0"
        + "C" + -r + "," + -r + " 0," + -r + " 0," + -3 * r
        + "C0," + -r + " " + r + "," + -r + " " + r + ",0"
        + "Z";
    }

    //add an orientation member to each node
    dataset.nodes.forEach(function (n, i, a) {
      n.orientation = {
        sinkCount: 0,
        totalX: 0,
        totalY: 0,
        reset: function () {
          this.sinkCount = this.totalX = this.totalY = 0;
        }
      };
      Object.defineProperty(n, "angle", {
        get: function () {
          var o = this.orientation;
          //angle of average vector
          return o.sinkCount ? Math.atan2(o.totalY / o.sinkCount, o.totalX / o.sinkCount) * 180 / Math.PI : 0;
        }
      });
    });
    function limitAngle(x) {
      var pi = Math.PI;
      return (x  > pi) ? 2 * pi - x : (x < -pi) ? 2 * pi + x : x;
    }
    //add link behaviour to tweek source node angle
    dataset.edges.forEach(function (l, i, a) {
      Object.defineProperties(l, {
        "angle": {
          get: function () {
            var s = this.source, t = this.target;
            return Math.atan2(-(t.y - s.y), t.x - s.x);
          }
        },
        "visitTarget": {
          value: function () {
            var n1 = this.target, n2 = this.source, t = n1.orientation;
            t.totalX += (n2.x - n1.x);
            t.totalY += -(n2.y - n1.y);
            t.sinkCount += 1;
          }
        }
      })
    });

    force.charge([-300])
        .start();

    //Every time the simulation "ticks", this will be called
    force.on("tick", function () {

      edges.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.x1 = d.source.x; })
         .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.y1 = d.source.y; })
         .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.x2 = d.target.x; })
         .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.y2 = d.target.y; });

      dataset.nodes.forEach(function (n, i, a) {
        n.orientation.reset();
      });
      dataset.edges.forEach(function (e, i, a) {
        e.visitTarget();
      });

      node.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ') rotate(' + -(d.angle - 90) + ")"
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works exactly how I intended it to as long as I rotate the nodes by -(d.angle - 90) instead of -(d.angle + 90). But then some edges have a part of them missing, why does that happen?

Comment: @Marianna, can you be more specific? I don't see any missing edges... For some reason your data has duplicate edges by the way, I think all of the links are doubled.

Comment: OK, when I rotated -90 like you require I see it.  It's the stroke of the teardrop which is white to give good definition when one is over the top of the other...

Comment: @Marianna, I changed the stroke from white to black so now you can see why the edges have missing bits.

Comment: Ahh yes, you're totally right!! Thanks for all your help!